# Working out the Grand Total of login attempts using root account using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have developed a script to calculate how many times some one has tried to login using a root account. I am using the resources from a separate document which contains all the login attempts.

```
 myfile = open ('/home/Parker4001/Desktop/loginAttempts','r')

 counter_root = 0

for line in myfile.readline():

     list_of_line1 = line.split(' ')

     if 'Failed password for root' in line:

            counter_root = counter_root +1

     print 'Attempt to login with root = ' , counter_root
```

This is the code i have so far which gives me the following output

```
  Attempt to login with root =  0
  Attempt to login with root =  0
  Attempt to login with root =  0
  Attempt to login with root =  0
  Attempt to login with root =  0
  Attempt to login with root =  0
```

The problem i am having is that i want a grand total rather than multiple lines + the counter_root doesn't seem to be adding up the attempts to log in any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that the line which prints `'Attempt to login with root'` is getting printed every time, regardless of whether or not the line matches. Not sure if this was intended or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Move the print statement back one level of indentation.
- Also change

  ```
  for line in myfile.readline():
  ```

  to

  ```
  for line in myfile:
  ```

  since `myfile.readline()` gives you just the first line of the file,
  and iterates over the *bytes* in the line. In contrast, `for
  line in myfile` iterates over the lines of the file.

Comment: @Parker4001 The best way to do so is by clicking on ✓.